# Show all resources used by an user using SLURM

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I want to estimate the total resources used by a user from SLURM since the creation of the user.
Most of the answers on the web show how we can check the resources of a finished job, but I want to list the total use of a specific user, no matter which jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for is [sreport](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sreport.html).

A typical usage would be

```
$ sreport cluster UserUtilizationByAccount start=2021-01-01 mylogin
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cluster/User/Account Utilization 2021-01-01T00:00:00 - 2022-08-22T23:59:59 (51750000 secs)
Usage reported in CPU Minutes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Cluster     Login     Proper Name         Account      Used   Energy
--------- --------- --------------- --------------- --------- --------
mycluster   mylogin        My Login       myaccount   5960990        0
```

Make sure to replace `mylogin` in the command line by the actual login you want the information about. Your can use `$USER` for your own login.

Depending on the configuration of your cluster, more trackable resources will be reportable. You can also look for the top users with

```
$ sreport user top
```

Comment: this give me no output.

Comment: this gives me something. `sreport cluster AccountUtilizationByUser user=s.1915438`. btw what is `used` column?

Comment: Accounting has to be configured in Slurm, and you have to make sure to select a period of time where the user has submitted jobs, and use a real login rather than `mylogin`. The `used` column is the number of `CPU Minutes` consumed over the period

Comment: That's awesome. I run  `sreport cluster AccountUtilizationByUser user=$USER start=2021-01-01` (suggest you adding this to the answer) and it worked as expected. What is the units for Energy?

Comment: The unit for energy is Joules